Local Visual Studio solution structure for eventual deployment to 2+ Azure App Services
I am trying to find a good approach to setting up local Visual Studio solutions for eventual deployment to Azure App Services (apologies if this is deemed opinion-based). My experience is normally IIS deployments - just starting on Azure.
Typically - a solution would contain (simplified for example):
Web Project, API Project, Data Access Library (shared between the two)
I know I could build the DAL as a nuget package and host as an artefact then reference it in the 2 front end projects. The issue there is that if I am making multiple changes I will be constantly pushing branches, waiting for pipelines to build and deploy the updated nuget package, updating the reference in the local dev branches before I can finally perform the integration test. Maybe this is a common approach though?
I had thought of creating separate solutions for each component - then before publishing to Azure for the first time, include the DAL project within the web projects for testing locally. Then when I am ready to deploy to staging, remove the project then build as above (create nuget etc.).
Is there a best practice for being able to develop and test locally and use CI/CD?
